# What is asynchronous processing when using setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When connected by serial, 'open' event occurs immediately, but if setTimeout is added, it will delay by that time. How can I fix this?

```
const Serialport = require('serialport');

class Serial {
  connect() {
    const client = new Serialport('COM2', {
      autoOpen: false,
    });

    console.time('Complete Connect');
    client.open(err => {
      console.timeEnd('Complete Connect');
    });
  }
}

const serialport = new Serial();
serialport.connect();

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('any work');
}, 3000);
```

prints:

```
1. any work
2. Complete Connect: 3025.978ms
```

Comment: The problem is specific to serialport, not setTimeout. Consider opening an issue. You shouldn't expect anything like that from setTimeout.

Comment: there is already a bug report [here](https://github.com/node-serialport/node-serialport/issues/1751)

Comment: When setTimeout is executed before receiving an event, there is a bug in which all events of the serialport module are delayed. Thank you.